# What is the picture of Gamma regularization in convex conjugate?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

In the theory of convex conjugation, it is said $F\ge F^{**}$. Here $F^{**}$ is said in fact the  Gamma regularization of $F$.

My question is that: is there any nice picture to understand the Gamma regularization? And when will $F\neq F^{**}$ (i.e. $F> F^{**}$)? is there any simple example?

As a picture, I know $F^{**}$ is kind of points from the set of tangent superplanes (Correct me if I am wrong). But I dont know when the set of tangent superplanes can not represent the original one, i.e. when $F\neq F^{**}$?

Comment: Possible duplicate:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2088635/what-is-the-geometric-difference-between-gamma-regularization-and-convex-conjuga

Comment: @DavidG.Stork it's different. And I think that one is not very clear. I know $F^{**}$ is kind of points from tangent superplane (Correct me if I am wrong). But I dont know when the tangent superplane can not represent the original one, i.e. when $F\neq F^{**}$?